# MySQL Workbench table looping

Tags: mysql-workbench

In the MySQL Workbench tool, this is what I need to accomplish.  Table A contains one unique member.  Table B can have anywhere from 1 to 7 rows for the member because this table contains all the different IDs a member can have, ie, first row contains ssn #, 2nd row contains subscriber_id, etc.  I need to link the 2 tables, obtaining ALL the member ids in the Table B rows, BUT I only want to produce one output line for the member.  Here is an example of the ouput line:

member_name      ssn#   subscriber#   another_id    another_id  another_id

John doe     123456789        634           0018        blank      3876

Basically, what I'm trying to do is loop thru Table B to obtain each type of id for a member.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Basically, you want to do a pivot?  All id from table b to be in 1 column per id?

Comment: Hi Daniel,

I want all the ids for one member to be in one output row, not column. For example, ssn would be in the first column, subscriber id in the 2nd column, infant id in the 3rd column, and so forth. I have a possibility of 7 different types of ids.  Each id is in a separate record on table B.